# Inline if Statement not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid, if-statement

For some reason, when I add the ternary if statement to this bit of code, a NullPointerException is thrown. I'm not sure quite why...any ideas? This is the method for jqGrid - returning the Json data.

```
var gridModel = from entity in vendorList.AsQueryable()
            select new
            {
                VendorId = "<a href='/Admin/DetailsPlan/" + entity.VendorId + "'><img src='/Images/next_icon_sm.png' class='icon' alt='View Vendor' /></a>",
                VendorNm = entity.VendorNm,
                Phone = (entity.Phone.Length < 5) ? String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(entity.Phone)) : entity.Phone,
                City = entity.City,
                State = entity.LkState.StateAbbr
            };
```

Can you not have a ternary if statement in that location?

Comment: What's a "unary" if statement?

Comment: @Peter: an example is *i++;* which the OP is obviously not having an issue with.  I think the word our good doctor is looking for is Ternary.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation  Correcting.

Comment: `? :` is called the *conditional operator.* (It's actually ternary, not unary.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question, is entity.Phone null?  If so, that would be the cause.

Side note: I have to say, that is an odd way of storing a phone number..

*UPDATE*

The problem is with the "entity.Phone.Length" part.  If Phone is null, then you can't access it's length property... hence the error.  So you need to add a null test.  Something like:

```
Phone = ((entity.Phone != null) && (entity.Phone.Length < 5)) ? String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(entity.Phone)) : entity.Phone
```

That way, if it is null you are just emitting a null value.

Comment: in some cases, it is null. however, if I have either String.Format(entity....) or if I just display the phone...no error..but the combination of the two make it not appear.

Answer (score 2):

```
var gridModel = from entity in vendorList.AsQueryable()
    let unformattedPhone = entity.Phone??string.Empty
    select new
    {
        VendorId = "<a href='/Admin/DetailsPlan/" + entity.VendorId + "'><img src='/Images/next_icon_sm.png' class='icon' alt='View Vendor' /></a>",
        VendorNm = entity.VendorNm,
        Phone = (unformattedPhone.Length < 5) ? String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(unformattedPhone)) : unformattedPhone,
        City = entity.City,
        State = entity.LkState.StateAbbr
    };
```

This may solve your problem.

Comment: It ended up being the `entity.phone.Length < 5` -- in some cases, entity.phone was null. However, your solution looks interesting - the line `let unformattedPhone = entity.Phone??string.empty` the double ?? means?

Comment: ?? Check if the value is NULL. If not NULL return the value otherwise return the string after the ?? :)